# Is there a way to modify variable inside the <body> tag as it's being displayed?

Tags: javascript, html

I am tring to implement a simple program that takes an integer and displays 10  themed times tables when the button is clicked. The idea to multiply the integer by the number of frogs and display the correct answer

```js
function doCalculations() {
  //Get the input field value
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
  var timestable = userInput.value;
}
```

```html
<h1>Enter a positive integer to generate FROG-timestable: </h1>
<input type="text" size="10" id="userInput"/>
</br>
<button onclick="doCalculations();">
  Generate FROG-timestable:
</button>
</br>
  <h2>
      
      +timestable *  = 
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  = 
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  = 
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
      </br>
      +timestable *  =
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope something like this is what you are trying to achieve.

Check the below snippet and get back to me in case if you require any clarifications.

I used jQuery to achieve it easily. You can do this with native JS also.

```js
function doCalculations() {
  //Get the input field value
  var inputValue = $('#userInput').val();
  var item = "";
  for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    var frog = "";
    for(var j = 0; j<i; j++) {
      frog += "";
    }
    
    item += "<h2>"+ inputValue + " * " + frog + " = "+ i*inputValue + "</h2>"
  }
  $('#frog-table').html(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Enter a positive integer to generate FROG-timestable: </h1>
<input type="text" size="10" id="userInput"/>
<button onclick="doCalculations();">
  Generate FROG-timestable:
</button>
<section id="frog-table">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is vey helpful. How would I implement this into native JS without the jQuery?

Comment: You want me to do it in native JS ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you expected.

```
 <script>
    function doCalculations(){
        //Get the input field value 
        var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
        var timestable = userInput.value;
        const cars = [];
        cars.length = timestable;
        var container = document.getElementById("demo");
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
          container.innerHTML += '<span >&#128056</span>';
        }
    }
   </script>
   <body>
     <h1>Enter a positive integer to generate FROG-timestable:</h1>
     <input type="text" size="10" id="userInput"/>
     </br>
     <button onclick="doCalculations();">Generate FROG-timestable</button>
     <div  id="demo"></div>
   </body>
```

I think this will help you